# is it possible to make fully functional shopping cart without MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, shopping-cart

because i have just a couple of products, and the encoding stuff in MySQL is just horrible.

I wanted to make products table in hebrew & tried to look for answers couldn't find any.

so know i gave up i just want to make a shopping cart using JUST PHP & AJAX, is it possible?

or do i have to use MySQL?

Answer (score 5):

It certainly is possible to create a shopping cart without mySQL, e.g. using flat files for data storage instead.

But if you have a mySQL based solution working, it's probably a better idea (and perfectly possible) to fix the encoding issues right there. mySQL is perfectly capable of storing hebrew characters with a UTF-8 character set.

If you provide details of what goes wrong at which point, you are very likely to get the problem solved on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

yes Its possible use Hierarchical instead of RDMS . Simple store all your data in XML file and use  xpath for query (instead of sql) .But the kind of problem you are facing might get solved using RDMS from another vendor such as Oracle or SQLLITe ,postgresql . Although I am pretty sure MSQL support Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you could store the ids, and counts in a cookie or better a session